# Missing points using QGIS2Web?

Tags: qgis, qgis2web, publishing

I have created a map with multiple points and path layers in QGIS 3.8 (Zanzibar). When I try to publish the map with the QGIS2Web plugin, there are two kind of results:

- When I use the "OpenLayers" option, it works quickly and it shows the raster map and the paths perfectly; however, only four of the many (>100) points are shown.
- When I use the "Leaflet" option, it does show all the points (although extremely slowly), but no raster map, and the functionality is really poor (very slow and barely visible).

I prefer to use the OpenLayers option, as it worked perfectly, except for all the missing points and labels.

Could anybody tell me how I can fix this?

The underlying dataset seems to be fine, as all the points are shown in the Leaflet option, and also when I load them in Geojson.

Answer (score 1):

Update: the problem is fixed!
I saved the layers with the missing points, which were previously saved as .csv files, as shapefiles, and uploaded the map with OpenLayers, and it worked perfectly.